# Instance member 'view' cannot be used on type 'GameScene'

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I recently updated to Xcode 7 Beta and now I am getting an error message "Instance member 'view' cannot be used on type 'GameScene' for line 5. Anyone got any ideas how to resolve this? Also if you want to be extra helpful, see my other question: [ConvertPointToView Function not working in Swift Xcode 7 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541160/convertpointtoview-function-not-working-in-swift-xcode-7-beta/32542255#32542255)

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var titleLabel: StandardLabel = StandardLabel(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 80, doCenter: true, text: "Baore", textColor: UIColor.redColor(), backgroundColor: UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0), font: "Futura-CondensedExtraBold", fontSize: 80, border: false, sceneWidth: view.scene.frame.maxX)

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.scene?.size = StandardScene.size
    self.view?.addSubview(titleLabel)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in (touches ) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    }
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
}
}
```

Comment: What is a `StandardLabel`?

Comment: @ABakerSmith Line 5. Don't worry about standard label, I am passing it valid parameters. I can show you it if you want but it's just got bunch of initializers. The issue is with 'view' and I get the error message "'view' cannot be used on type 'GameScene'"

Comment: @ABakerSmith Ok well are you using Xcode beta 7? No, StandardLabel is a subclass of UILabel. It's got nothing to with self.view?.addSubview(titleLabel). It only pertains to line 5 when 'view' is mentioned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is you're using `self` before your `GameScene` instance has been fully initialised. If you take a look at the end of line 5:

```
var titleLabel = StandardLabel(..., sceneWidth: view.scene.frame.maxX) 
// Would be a good idea to use `let` here if you're not changing `titleLabel`.
```

Here you're referencing `self.view`.

To solve this I would lazily initialise `titleLabel`:

```
lazy var titleLabel: StandardLabel = StandardLabel(..., sceneWidth: self.view!.scene.frame.maxX) 
// You need to explicitly reference `self` when creating lazy properties.
// You also need to explicitly state the type of your property.
```

From [The Swift Programming Language: Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html), on Lazy Stored Properties:

> A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value is not calculated until the first time it is used.

Therefore, by the time you use `titleLabel` in `didMoveToView`, `self` has been fully initialised and it's safe to use `self.view!.frame.maxX` (see below for how to achieve the same result without needing to force unwrap `view`).

---

**Edit**

Taking a look at the picture of your error:

[image]

Your first problem is you need to explicitly state the type of the property when using lazy variables. Secondly you need to explicitly reference self when using lazy properties:

```
lazy var label: UILabel = 
    UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.view!.scene!.frame.maxX, y: 5, width: 5, height: 5))
```

You could clean this up a bit though by not using `view` to get to `scene` - you've already got a reference to `scene` - it's `self`!

```
lazy var label: UILabel = 
    UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.maxX, y: 5, width: 5, height: 5))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix it. I simplified it by not using standard label: http://i1087.photobucket.com/albums/j461/niiooo/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-12%20at%208.31.35%20PM.png

Comment: My bad, I forgot `view` was an Optional. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your effort

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much!

Comment: You've done plenty but if you want to be extra helpful I've got another issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541160/convertpointtoview-function-not-working-in-swift-xcode-7-beta?lq=1

Comment: http://i1087.photobucket.com/albums/j461/niiooo/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-12%20at%208.56.45%20PM.png